# excel countif entire row in a table

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a structured table in excel 2016.

I want to have a cell to count the number of cells across the entire row within the table if it matches my criteria.

I have tried putting this formula in column A on each row `=COUNTIF(Table[@],"my criteria")` but that does not count properly.

However, this works: `=COUNTIF(Table[@[ColB]:[ColH]],"my criteria")`. But since my table will expand, I don't want to specify the column name `[ColB]`, I want to refer to the entre row in the table.

| A header | countif | colC | colD | colE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | formula | A |  | C |
| Second | formula |  | B | C |

`formula` = `=COUNTIF(Table[@],"A")` does not work

`formula` = `=COUNTIF(Table[@[colC]:[colE]],"A")` works

My table will expand both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Your table expands horizontally? That is a rather peculiar situation for data management. If it only expands one direction, you should swap the axes and allow the table to expand downward (vertically). Are you open to VBA solutions (you will need to resave your workbook as a macro-enabled workbook).

Comment: My data expand both horizontally and vertically. If non-macro solution is viable, I would prefer not making the file macro-enable just to make this countif function work.

Comment: I am not as big on worksheet functions as I am with VBA. I will go ahead and post my VBA solution and hopefully you can wait to see if someone comes up with a non-VBA solution later and fall back on mine if not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ***Please Note:** This solution is only available if you chose to use VBA. VBA does not work in web versions of Excel. Please ensure that you **resave** your workbook as a **macro-enabled workbook** before proceeding.*

You can choose to use VBA and create your own custom worksheet formula. Since this question didn't start out as a VBA issue, I will be a bit more detailed on the process of setting this up as opposed to just throwing you some code and you having to figure out what to do with it.

1. After you've re-saved your workbook as a macro-enabled workbook, open the VBA Editor (VBE) by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> simultaneously.
2. In the VBE, click Insert > Module. You should now see Module1 highlighted on the left side bar (The project Explorer).
3. Copy and paste the following code in the blank area of the module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function GetMyRowCount(Criteria As Variant) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tblRng As Range, RowRng As Range
    With Application.Caller
        Set ws = .Worksheet
        Set tblRng = ws.Range(.ListObject.Name)
        Set RowRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(.Row, .Column + 1), ws.Cells(.Row, tblRng.Columns.Count))
    End With
    
    GetMyRowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RowRng, Criteria)

End Function
```

4. Now use this UDF (User Designed Function) in your worksheet. In the column you would like the calculation to be in, simply type `=GetMyRowCount("My Criteria")` and it should calculate.

---

To point out how this code works in more detail:

- `Application.Caller` is referring to the cell that this function is located in. Because we now know the location of the cell, VBA can use it's location to obtain the row data from it (which is why you don't need an argument for the row #).
- `RowRng` is getting the starting point of the column within the `ws.Range(...)` function with the first `ws.Cells(...)` function. `.Row` is the row # from the `GetMyRowCount` function (using `Application.Caller.Row` method), and the `3` is simply the static column C.
- The way we grab the last column we need is by counting the total # of columns within the table: `ws.Cells(.Row, tblRng.Columns.Count)`

Using the information we obtained from bullets 2 and 3, we can establish the entire range of the lookup we need, and then place this range into your `CountIf()` function, along with the criteria you passed with the function's argument:

```
GetMyRowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RowRng, Criteria)
```

---

As you can see in the following example, I wanted to count the number of times in the row the number `1` occurred:

[image]

Another example showing it works with text as well by using "Apple" as the criteria:

[image]

Comment: I have to use it in multiple tables with different starting columns. How should I modify?

Comment: I have updated the above code to now get the table name automatically using `.ListObject.Name` property, and to obtain the column automatically, using the `.Column` property of `Application.Caller` as opposed to hard-coding in the 3rd column. This assumes that the data to check for will always be to the right of the formula. If not, let me know as it's an easy fix (but will require you to use another argument in your formula).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `=COUNTIF(B:B,"my citeria")`, so if your Column is A, range would be `A:A`, for B it is `B:B`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Incorrect counts. I think there is a circular reference problem because the cell I place my formula is in the same table same row. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Can you share data?

Comment: Edited in the question

Comment: Try this: =COUNTIF(B:B,"my citeria") , so if your Column is A, range would be A:A, for B it is B:B, letme know if this helps

Comment: I want to count row not column, formula in cell A2: countif row 2 with "my criteria"